# How to output audio from ytdl to microphone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ytdl

I'm trying to play audio like this `ytdl(url, { quality: 'audioonly' })` to virtual microphone(VB cable driver), but i'm not sure how.

I don't know how to play it, I'm new to JavaScript, and I can't find anything on the internet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give this approach a try, but are you sure that you need use this Virtual Microphone thing?

General possible sequence of steps:

- Assuming VB-Cable driver is installed your computer:
- Use ytdl to download the audio from the YouTube video and store it as a buffer or a file.
- Use an audio library like Node-Webkit-Audio to play the audio buffer or file through the VB-Cable virtual microphone. You'll need to select the VB-Cable virtual microphone as the output device in the audio library's configuration.
- Configure your system's audio settings to use the VB-Cable virtual microphone as the default input device. This will allow any other applications on your computer to receive the audio that you're outputting through ytdl.
- Here's an example of how to use ytdl and Node-Webkit-Audio to output audio to the VB-Cable virtual microphone:

javascript code:

```
    const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
    const { AudioContext, GainNode } = require('node-web-audio');
    const { createReadStream } = require('fs');
    
    const url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ';
    
    // Download the audio from the YouTube video
    const audioStream = ytdl(url, { quality: 'highestaudio' });
    
    // Create an AudioContext and a GainNode to control the volume
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    const gainNode = new GainNode(audioContext, { gain: 1 });
    
    // Create a ReadableStream from the audioStream and pipe it into a Node-Webkit-Audio instance
    const audioFile = createReadStream('./audio.mp3'); // replace this with your own audio file
    audioFile.pipe(new NodeWebkitAudio({
      context: audioContext,
      destination: gainNode,
      autoplay: true,
      loop: false
    }));
    
    // Set the VB-Cable virtual microphone as the output device
    NodeWebkitAudio.setSinkId('CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)');
    
    // Connect the audio to the virtual microphone
    gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

Comment: how do i get the nodewebkitaudio class?

Comment: also what package is node-web-audio, cant find it